Spock Mock doesnt work inside lambda function
I can't find something about it, but it seems like the Spock mock doesn't work inside my lambda function. I have tried:
    RestTemplateAdapter restTemplateAdapter = Mock(RestTemplateAdapter)
    int maxRety = 5
    String baseUrl = "baseUrl"
    ProductRequestPort productRequestPort = new ProductRequestAdapter( restTemplateAdapter, baseUrl, maxRety)

        def "should throw erro"() {
        given:
        String errorMsg = "Error test message"
        Long customerCode = 1234L

        when:
        productRequestPort.find(customerCode)
        then:

        maxRety * restTemplateAdapter.exchange(_, _, _, _) >> { throw new RuntimeException(errorMsg) }
        GatewayException error = thrown(GatewayException.class)
        error.getMessage() == "Error when trying to get products."

    }

The method im trying to mock:
    public CompletableFuture<ProductListResponse> find(Long customerCode) {
    String url = BASE_URL + customerCode;
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>();

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        return retrieveProductListResponse(customerCode, url, entity);
    });
}

    private ProductListResponse retrieveProductListResponse(Long customerCode, String url, HttpEntity<?> entity) {
    int attempt = 0;
    while (attempt < MAX_RETRIES) {
        try {
            ResponseEntity<ProductListResponse> response = restTemplateAdapter.exchange(
                    url,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    entity,
                    ProductListResponse.class
            );
            return response.getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            attempt++;
        }
    }
    throw new GatewayException(ERROR_GETTING_PRODUCTS);}

I recive from the test execution:
    Too few invocations for:

maxRety * restTemplateAdapter.exchange(_, _, _, _) >> { throw new RuntimeException(errorMsg) }   (1 invocation)

And the Mock just return a "null" as response from restTemplateAdapter.
I placed my RestTemplate class inside an adapter because I thought Spock couldn't mock it properly, but even with the interface the error persist. If I open the method retrieveProductListResponse to public and call it from the test spock is capable of mock it. Due to this, I suspect that the issue might be related to the lambda inside CompletableFuture.

Your problem is not related to any nesting.
You call productRequestPort.find which immediately returns a CompletableFuture and does the work asynchronously.
Then you immediately check the outcome, which of course fails, as you did not wait for the work to complete.
Wait for the CompletableFuture to complete before checking the expectations.

Thx! It worked, I just put "
when:
productRequestPort.findByCustomerCode(customerCode).get()
then:
" and it worked.

But.. why does the mock says it was called one time ?

Why not?
You do this asynchronously, so one call was already made when the expectation was made.

Sorry for my newbility, but can u help me understand de process? in this case, my test fineshed before the other thread can execute the lambda function, correct? So, because of it it not throw the error as I expected.
But, why the Mock says it was called one time ? Shoudnt tell me it wasnt called or, at least, changed the number of times it was called for each attemp i have done?
As I understand, the CompletableFuture works as the async/await of JavaScript, doesnt? If i do not call the "get()" it should execute in paralel from the beginer of the process, correct?

It's a bit different than in JavaScript, as JavaScript has only one thread where in Java you can have many and thus things running in parallel. You tell it to execute that action in parallel, it starts to do so and at the same time you continue in your test code and check the expectation. That it always says it was called one time is just coincidence.
